# One Drive connector in React/Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, onedrive, connector

I need to create connector for onedrive in my Reactjs/Nodejs application in which user can enter his/her oneDrive details once and than my app can automatically download video files from his/her onedrive every night on specific time. User do not has to go through some Authentication etc. Once user gives necessary details my application can access its files forever unless he/she remove it themselves from application. This is something I can't get a head start. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this ? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Start somehow, and get back here, if your stuck with any code. That way you learn the most. Just create a roadmap of tasks to do, and do task per task. It does not have to be beauty at beginning, you can refactor at the moment you realize how something had to be done..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment. Read through your question, and make small, maintanable tasks.

Then do one task after the other. Focus on one single task and you will get it done.

#### Example task list:

- Investigate `Onderive API`. Try to login somehow and receive a token. Learn how to use the API to fullfill your needs. Start by only logging in. Persistance comes later.
- Investigate how to login and download a file from onedrive.
- Get a script running where you login and download a file
- Investigate in `nodejs` and get a server up and running
- Setup a `reactjs` project Hello world
- Combine `react` and `nodejs` with your knowledge about One drive and design your architecture (more or less..) Define API Endpoints or whatever and try to use them from client. First implement them on server, then call them from client.. Don't loose time by styling your stuff. Apply the styles at the time your technical stuff finished.
- Try to login on client and then download a file. Decide whether the download should go through server OR directly from client.

#### Step by Step

This is an example list. Just write down all the mini tasks you have to do and then proceed by doing one by one.

Before starting with the project, investigate all the steps and check out if its technically possible. In the end you can build up the project like a puzzle with all the information you gathered before..

Good luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I can login user, get access token and refresh tokens and I can get files too, but when I login another user, like my user login with his/her another gmail account, the tokens of previous account no longer work. They give unauthenticated error.

Comment: Then open up a question with that problem.. Show the code you have.. Why do you then ask this general question?